# Real-time updating fields based on user input

Tags: c#, field, real-time

total n00b here, I'm building a simple app to do a few calculations. As of now I'm stuck as to get my fields to connect to my variables and display the results real-time. I'm getting errors in regards to variable initialisation.

Here's a sample of something similar of what I want to achieve:
https://media.giphy.com/media/xUPGcK74nHdNpEnmKs/giphy.gif

Here's my UI:
https://image.ibb.co/hUvm3F/2017_05_29_13_46_19_Risk_Calc_Form1_cs_Design.png

And here's my code so far:

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            double price;               //entered by user or fetched
            double balance;             //entered by user or fetched   
            double equity;              //entered by user or fetched
            Int32  leverage;            //entered by user
            double availableUnits;      //calculated value
            double margin80;            //calculated margin of 80%
            double margin50;            //calculated margin of 50%
            double marginCall;          //calculated margin of 30%
            double marginStopOut;       //calculated margin of 15%
            Int32  units;               //units for trading, entered by user
            double TP;                  //Take Profit entered by user
            double SL;                  //Stop Loss entered by user
            double tradeStopOut;        //calculated rate at which trade has 100% loss
            double marginUsed;          //calculated funds invested in the market
            double positionValue;       //calculated funds invested accounting for leverage
            double profitCash;          //calculated profit in currency
            double lossCash;            //calculated loss in currency
            double profitPct;           //calculated profit in percentage
            double lossPct;             //calculated loss in percentage
            double balanceLoss;         //calculated balance + loss
            double balanceWin;          //calculated balance + win
            double rrr;                 //calculated risk reward ratio


            //calculating the number of available units to trade
            availableUnits = equity / price * leverage;

            //calculating critical margin levels
            margin80 = balance * 0.8;
            margin50 = balance * 0.5;
            marginCall = balance * 0.3;
            marginStopOut = balance * 0.15;

            //calculating trade stop out level
            tradeStopOut = price - (price / leverage);

            //calculating margin used and position value
            marginUsed = (price * units) / leverage;
            positionValue = price * units;

            //calculating profit and loss ( cash, percentile, +balance)
            profitCash = units * TP - (units * price);
            lossCash = units * SL - (units * price);

            profitPct = profitCash / balance * 100;
            lossPct = lossCash / balance * 100;

            balanceLoss = price + lossCash;
            balanceWin = price + profitCash;

            //calculating risk reward ratio (RRR)
            rrr = SL / TP;


            //UI TEXTBOXES

            balance = Convert.ToDouble(balanceTextbox.Text);
            equity = Convert.ToDouble(equityTextbox.Text);
            price = Convert.ToDouble(priceTextbox.Text);
            leverage = Convert.ToInt32(leverageTextbox.Text);
            units = Convert.ToInt32(unitsTextbox.Text);
            TP = Convert.ToDouble(tpTextbox.Text);
            SL = Convert.ToDouble(slTextbox.Text);

            //UI LABELS

            availableUnits = Convert.ToDouble(availableUnitsLabel.Text);
            marginUsed = Convert.ToDouble(marginUsedLabel.Text);
            positionValue = Convert.ToDouble(positionValueLabel.Text);
            profitCash = Convert.ToDouble(profitCashLabel.Text);
            lossCash = Convert.ToDouble(lossCashLabel.Text);
            profitPct = Convert.ToDouble(profitPctLabel.Text);
            lossPct = Convert.ToDouble(lossPctLabel.Text);
            tradeStopOut = Convert.ToDouble(tradeStopOutLabel.Text);
            rrr = Convert.ToDouble(rrrLabel.Text);
            balanceLoss = Convert.ToDouble(balanceLossLabel);
            balanceWin = Convert.ToDouble(balanceWinLabel);
            margin80 = Convert.ToDouble(margin80Label.Text);
            margin50 = Convert.ToDouble(margin50Label.Text);
            marginCall = Convert.ToDouble(marginCallLabel.Text);
            marginStopOut = Convert.ToDouble(marginStopOutLabel.Text);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know the UI tech you are using, but if it is WPF then you can use Databinding with the help of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which syncs the properties and UI components in real time. If you are using good old WinForms, then you need to hook into events of various user controls and update necessary properties manually. UPDATE: Ok I saw you are using WinForms, so you can hook into events of controls and then update necessary properties.

Comment: What does this have to do with real-time? If you want the values to be updated on each keypress event, handle the keypress event

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't know how to put it other than real-time because when I searched for a solution, most examples I found included a button which I don't want to press each time I change a value. So it has to change all variables real-time as I change other values.

Some great answers here already, will test a few things.

Comment: @G10Link that's because you were searching for the wrong thing. There are *tons* of examples on how to use the keypress or keydown events. The button just generates a `Click` event after all, just like most clickable controls

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but it's ok. I'll keep trying... Thanks everyone for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one function to do all the calculation and make it update fields accordingly, and call it upon change of input field value, add text change listener for all the inputs you want, and call that function on each change :)
[example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add events

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            balanceTextbox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(balanceTextbox_Changed);
        }
        private void balanceTextbox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```